# Android: R.java is missing

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No generated R.java file in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085959/no-generated-r-java-file-in-my-project)

Long story short: I am trying the NotePad sample code and my R.java class is not being generated.
I have tried suggestions from the following posts:

- Cleaning the project ([Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating), [No generated R.java file in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085959/no-generated-r-java-file-in-my-project))
- Looking for references to android.R.*; ([R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error))
- Checking my xml files for errors

But I still don't have an R.java class. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're having any errors on your `res` folder means, sometimes it'll happen this. In that time. Just try to remove that errors and clean again. It'll work surely.

Comment: look this previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085959/no-generated-r-java-file-in-my-project

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse and importing the project again and building, Eclipse gets its knickers in a twist sometimes

Comment: @SpK I just double checked my res folder and nothing is wrong with it.

Comment: You can open the Eclipse Problems View to see if there is an Error in XML Files or missing Library etc.: Click on "Window" - "Show View" - "Problems"

Comment: @EdChum Thanks, your suggestion worked perfectly. Please post your suggestion as an answer so I can pick it and upvote it please! :D

Comment: @MissPiplup OK, very common error on Eclipse and very frustrating, also remember to save any changes to your layout.xml files if you want your new widget ids or strings to compile correctly.

Comment: fixed errors in AndroidManifest.xml in my project, and then rebuild, R.java generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart Eclipse and reimport the project again and build.
Eclipse sometimes gets its knickers in a twist with the R generated class.