# Getting strings from the strings.xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm currently working on internationalization to my android application. This is the way I try to get the strings from the `string.xml`

```
tv.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.));
```

But Eclipse does not suggest any of my pre defined strings, just the standard `Android Strings`. My Folder structure look like this:

```
res/values/strings.xml
```

and

```
res/values-NO/strings.xml
```

I can see that the strings in these to files has some memory addresses in the `R.java` file, like this one for instance:

```
public static final int enterPassword=0x7f06003c;
```

I tried to `Clean` the Project, but its strange that eclipse doesnt suggest anything, the string exist in the `R.java`

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should import you R class.

`import xxx.xxx.R;`

not

`import android.R;`

Answer (score 4):

your xml looks like this:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <resources>
      <string name="yellow">Yellow</string>
    </resources>
```

and in java code:

```
  tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.yellow));
```

and import android.R eventhough error exists than try to run the program than it will go off

Comment: That is correct, I try to get the text in the `enterPassword`

Comment: try to run the program and clean the project--> build the project than it will show

Answer (score 1):

import `R` with your `Package Path` instead of android.

like `import com.example.R`

instead of `import android.R;`

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the imported R file path
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085959/no-generated-r-java-file-in-my-project/4087079#4087079) for more information

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Resources resources = getResources();

        String string = resources.getString(R.string.text);

              TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
                tv.settext(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String tab_label = getResources().getString(R.string.));
```

and ensure that you are not imported **android.R**