# What happened to my R.java file?

Tags: r.java-file

I was working on a project and when i cleaned it, it no longer recognized R in any of my commands. For example setContentView(R.layout.add_or_modify); it doesnt know what R is. I checked my generated files and i noticed that my R.java is gone. What happened? and how do i get it back?

Comment: [Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085959/no-generated-r-java-file-in-my-project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085959/no-generated-r-java-file-in-my-project)

Answer (score 0):

You probably made an error in one your .xml files (layout probably) if I remember correctly, go through those and make sure there are no invalid xml elements