# Zxing library cannot be resolved

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, r.java-file

I am developing app with zxing library. I imported the `zxing` project into my work place. When i importing there were some problems i faced.

1. Compile the project by `java 1.7`. I done it.
2. `CameraConfigurationUtils` was missing. I copied from the `library source`.
3. `Resource id's` cannot be used to check in the `switch case`. I changed it to `if else`.

But finally there is a broblem in the 
1. `emailResult.getTos()` was not resolved in `EmailAddressResultHandler` 
2. Then i built the project there comes the problem **`R.java`** cannot be resolved throughout my application.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: this sound more like a compilation/IDE problem and not a zxing library problem. checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085959/no-generated-r-java-file-in-my-project

Comment: @MemLeak I double checked no android.R imports. And my project build target with android 4.2.2. And my minsdk version with 15 and targetsdk version with 18.

Comment: i have same problem have you resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you used the 3.10 or older pre-built jar, but your ZXing  project is from GitHub which should use 3.1.1-snapshot.jar build with maven. The APIs had been modified last month according https://github.com/zxing/zxing/commit/8158984458f6db59b462ef2b4dd270321c66f203

I just build the core-3.1.1-SNAPSHOT and test it, it works. You can get it and replace your core.jar and try it :). I put them on my GitHub.
https://github.com/voyagewu/ZXing_library/tree/master/core-3.1.1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 1):

Lots wrong here.

`CameraConfigurationUtils` is not missing: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationUtils.java

`EmailAddressResultHandler` has those methods: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/EmailAddressResultHandler.java I suspect you are adding several versions of the library to your project somehow.

You are trying to use `android/` as a library project if you see that error about `switch`. It is not a library, and is not supposed to be used that way.

`R.java` is generated by your build. You haven't set up your Android project correctly.

I suggest that if you're struggling with using Maven and Android projects, that you should not be copying project code into your project. I think you are headed towards using the project in a way inconsistent with the license: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/License-Questions It would be far easier for you to start by integrating by `Intent`: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent

Answer (score 0):

Update the pre-built jar library: download recent snapshot/nightly builds from
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/zxing/core/

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy CameraConfigurationUtils from: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationUtils.java

and paste file into android project's com.google.zxing.client.android.camera package..

error gone for me.