# cannot resolve symbol 'CameraConfigurationUtils' on Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, zxing

I recently checked out some code from Git on Android Studio. The project uses barcodeScanner, I use CameraConfigurationManager.java but when I check I get an error from CameraConfigurationUtils.
 Might anyone know why? Thanks!

code:

```
 private CameraConfigurationManager() {
  }

  static void configure(Camera camera) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(1280, 720);
    //parameters.setPreviewSize(1920, 1080);
    configureAdvanced(parameters);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    //logAllParameters(parameters);
  }

  private static void configureAdvanced(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    CameraConfigurationUtils.setBestPreviewFPS(parameters);
    CameraConfigurationUtils.setBarcodeSceneMode(parameters);
    CameraConfigurationUtils.setVideoStabilization(parameters);
    CameraConfigurationUtils.setMetering(parameters);
    CameraConfigurationUtils.setZoom(parameters, ZOOM);
  }

  private static void logAllParameters(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.INFO)) {
      for (String line : CameraConfigurationUtils.collectStats(parameters).split("\n")) {
        Log.i(TAG, line);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197401/zxing-library-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: I tried it but it not working or maybe I do not understand the those answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded the zxing source code. The `glass` module depends on `android-common` which has the class you're looking for.

Comment: Can you please explain it to me , What did I do wrong or what must I do to correct it.

Comment: You will need to include the CameraConfigurationUtils class in your project, which is [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android-core). @Sean Owen, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Koh I rolled back your edit, since it was pointing to another project. You do not generally consume libraries by copying source code; you can and should use Maven for instance, or grab the compiled .jar for it.