# Unable to run hello world program on new ADT Plugin Version 23.0.4.1468518

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a newbie to android development. Download ADT bundle for windows and installed the Android 4.1.2 through SDK manager.Even installed ADT plugin through Eclipse Juno. When I created the first Project-Hello World , I am getting so many build errors in eclipse.
Here are the 12 errors:

1.ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type    MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 8  Java Problem

2.ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type    MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 12 Java Problem

3.ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type    MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 32 Java Problem

4.error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.   styles.xml /HelloWorld/res/values line 7    Android AAPT Problem

5.R cannot be resolved to a variable        MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 13 Java Problem

6.R cannot be resolved to a variable        MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 19 Java Problem

7.R cannot be resolved to a variable        MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 29 Java Problem

8.The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved  MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 3  Java Problem

9.The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type MainActivity   MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 19 Java Problem

10.The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method   MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 11 Java Problem

11.The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method  MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 17 Java Problem

12.The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method    MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 24 Java Problem

Please suggest how to resolve it. Even I am unable to create emulator through AVD manager.[image: Ok Button Disable]

[image: Failed To load AVD manager]

Comment: Make sure you have the correct version of Java installed. At first glance, it seems to me that you don't have the correct libraries installed or eclipse is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: What are 'MainActivity.java' and what's 'helloworld.java?' Look at the error messages again and have a think.

Comment: I like to just attach my own device and test it there....its faster and more realistic

Answer (score 0):

After updating to SDK Tools to rev. 22 for the first time, you may need to relaunch Android SDK Manager again and install a new item: Android SDK Build-tools.

[No generated R.java file in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085959/no-generated-r-java-file-in-my-project)

Answer (score 0):

Well there is multiple possibilities but it seems that you are trying to run an application with a certain api level with something that doesn't support it.  This is my guess, what was the minimum api level that you chose when setting the application up and are you trying to test on an emulator or physical device? Also go to your sdk manager option and tell me what you have installed.